# How to make apps visible from search but not visible otherwise?

Tags: android, google-play

In the Google play store there is a "More by X" part on the page of the App. I want it so that the app is available by searching for it, but the other apps are not visible when you click on it.

The reason for this is that companies do not want to see similar apps created for competitors.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no setting for this in the Google Play Developer Dashboard.

To avoid having apps created for other companies appear at the bottom of the page for their app, the company needs to create their own Google Play Developer account. You can then have the app transferred to them so it shows up under their company name.

But that only works if you're OK with not having the apps under your (business) name in Google Play. If you're not then they just have to live with it.